# Handling clicks on a List of menu items in React and material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a menu component in React which utilises material-ui List component that looks sort of like this:

```
handleMenuItemClick() {
    // go to route defined in the ListItem
}

class MenuList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <List
                    onClick={this.handleMenuItemClick}
                >
                    <ListItem button route="/dashboard">
                        <DashboardIcon /> <ListItemText primary="Dashboard" />
                    </ListItem>
                    <ListItem button route="/investments">
                        <InvestmentsIcon /> <ListItemText primary="My investments" />
                    </ListItem>
                </List>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to go to different route defined the route attribute of the ListItem. How do I do this in React?

I don't want separate click handlers for each of the menu items.

Comment: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/92bd073015b9cc0dff3a26195fcb49153ddaab78/docs/src/modules/components/AppDrawerNavItem.js#L71-L83

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
                       <ListItem
                            component={Link}
                            to="/"
                            button >
```

Referenced from a [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/7956)

Comment: Thanks, that's even better than I thought